# ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but " ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (5,) and (4,)

Tags: python, data-science

I´m trying to plot the mean, standard deviation, standard error(part of the code is Norwegian)  but I got the error:

`4.23 4.27] Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/tmp/sessions/1b82d4907d9faf0a/main.py", line 20, in <module>     plot(mengde, y_snitt,"bo")   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2767, in plot     return gca().plot(   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1635, in plot     lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 312, in __call__     yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 498, in _plot_args     raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but " ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (5,) and (4,)`

My code:

```
from pylab import*

# Leser inn lengden av REM-søvn for de ulike konsentrasjonenen med etanol
y_0 = array([88.6, 73.2, 91.4, 68.0, 75.2])
y_1 = array([63.0, 53.9, 69.2, 50.1, 71.5])
y_2 = array([44.9, 59.5, 40.2, 56.3, 38.7])
y_4 = array([31.0, 39.6, 45.3, 25.2, 22.7])

# Bestemmer gj.nsitt, standaravik og standarfeil for de fire konsentrasjonene
y_snitt = array([mean(y_0), mean(y_1), mean(y_2), mean (y_4)])
y_stav = array([std(y_0,ddof=1), std(y_1,ddof=1), std(y_2,ddof=1), std(y_4,ddof=1)])
SE = y_stav/sqrt(5)

# Skriv ut gj.nsitt, standaravik og standardfeil
print("Gjennomsnitt", around(y_snitt,2))
print("Standarfeil", around(SE,2))

# Plottr gj.snitt med feilmarginer
mengde = array ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
plot(mengde, y_snitt,"bo")
vlines(mengde, y_snitt-2*SE, y_snitt+2*SE,"red")
ylabel("REM-søvn (min)")

x = linspace (0, 4, 100)
y = 77.30 * 0.803**x
plot(x, y, "--")
show()
```

I have tried googling the problem but I haven't found a solution yet. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your variables `mengde` and `y_snitt` have different shapes. One of them is an array of length 4 while the other one is an array of length 5. To plot them, they need to have the same length.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have mengde array has a length of 5 while the y_snitt array has a length of 4.

simply remove the first element from the mengde array, since you only have 4 values for y_snitt

```
mengde = array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```